# do i need a transit visa for Paris is coming from the US to Czech Republic?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, paris

I am really confused about the transit visa. I have a 2hr layover in Paris from the US on my way to Prague. DO i need to apply for a transit Visa?

Comment: @choster it doesn't matter -- he is traveling to Prague, so he must have a Schengen visa or a passport from a country that doesn't require one.

Comment: @MichaelHampton actually this is not a case of transiting in the Schengen area because the final destination is Prague.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have a visa for the Czech Republic, or that you are a citizen of a country whose citizens do not need a visa for short stays (for example, the United States), and that you are going for a short stay.

If this is true, you do not need a transit visa for France.  France and the Czech republic have common border controls, including a common visa regime, because they both belong to the Schengen area.  You will clear immigration in Paris, and your flight to Prague will have no border controls -- it will be like a domestic flight in the US.